# Eliminate extra space on right side of hslider. Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am building a mediaplayer in flex /as3 using OSMF
I have issue in seekbar's width, I have given its width to stage.width but still there might be a problem with skin or what but I am having extra space on right side of hslider.
Any one know why it is? or how to remove that extra white space?
My current width of that hslider is set to `100%` still its showing extra space.
I apologize for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try `right =-5`(or the amount required) on the hslider. Also see if the outer container has margin or gap set between the components. Hslider does not has default margin or gap or padding applied on it as per the [api](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/HSlider.html). Post your code if none of these work.

Comment: I have tried but this didn't worked, instead it made it to create a scrollbar.
here is code of my mxslider and above it there is nothing that is giving gap or anything else

`<mx:HSlider id="seek" showDataTip="false" x="-5" y="{prgy}" width="{prgrwidth}" height="0" buttonMode="true"
     chromeColor="#B8AFAF" enabled="true" labelOffset="0" liveDragging="true"
     showTrackHighlight="true" maxHeight="-3" snapInterval="0"
     thumbSkin="images.CustomSliderThumbSkin"  allowThumbOverlap="true" useHandCursor="true"/>
`

Comment: I am able to make it till the end but then scrollbar appears. Is there any way to hide and disable scrollbar?

Comment: try settin the horizontalscrollpolicy =off

Comment: can i set this for stage as a whole? is there any property like this for full screen stage?
I appreciate your help and thank you for being helpful :)

Comment: Most of the uicomponents with scroller has this property. there is one for the vertical scroll also.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me here :)
I was asking about StageMode.FULL_SCREEN;

Comment: did not find that proprty on the stage, may be one of the child which shows the scroll should be set this property